# memory map a device file in linux kernel

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

In linux kernel, when I do

cat /proc/pid/maps

I get some entries that map the files in /dev/XXX. I understand this is the device file, which corresponds to hardware devices instead of actual files. How does the memory management in linux kernel handle such mapping? What happens if I read or write to /dev/XXX?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I believe is correct: When a device maps a particular memory region, say X to Y, a `vm_area_struct` (`vm_start` = X and `vm_end` = Y) is associated with that region and then mapped into the process's virtual memory map. That `vm_are_struct` is then associated with a `vm_operations_struct` that supplied by the device driver.

That means a device driver will implement some or all the functions in the `vm_operations_struct`. The most important one being the `fault` function.

Now, assume the process references a page in that area for the first time. That will trigger the page fault handler. The page fault has this code in it:

```
3646               if (pte_none(entry)) {
3647                         if (vma->vm_ops) {
3648                                 if (likely(vma->vm_ops->fault))
3649                                         return do_linear_fault(mm, vma, address,
3650                                                 pte, pmd, flags, entry);
3651                         }
3652                         return do_anonymous_page(mm, vma, address,
3653                                                  pte, pmd, flags);
3654                 }
```

Notice line #3648. It checks if the `vm_operations_struct` is implemented for that `vm_area_struct`. If it is, it will call the "`fault`" member function. Look at some of the implementations for that function.

The implementation of this function should return a pointer to page struct. The page itself will be allocated and populated with data by the device driver (i.e. "`fault`" function).

The rest of the page handler will associate a pte entry with that page. That means the next time the page is accessed and causes a page fault the check pte_none on line #3646 will fail. This will result in skipping the device driver fault function the second time that particular page is referenced.

Note: a `vm_area_struct` may be mapped to more than one page struct. So, one `vm_area_struct` may fit N*4KB. Assuming `PAGE_SIZE` is 4KB and N=1,2,...,X